# Tried creating tabs in product detail page in flutter. But tabs is in stateful widget. When I inserted tab class name in home class, getting error

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to insert tabs below elevated button. When I am using it as separate file, its working fine. Please suggest any ways to insert tabs in this code. I am in the learning stage of flutter.Here is the code link [on codepen](https://codepen.io/Venkat01/pen/PoOvaRR).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Home());
  }
}

class TabsPart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TabsPartState createState() => _TabsPartState();
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            image: AssetImage('assets/images/img1.png'))),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.lightBlue,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Center(
                              child: Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
                                width: 12 * 1.5,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const ProductNameAndPrice(),
                            const Spacing(),
                            const ProductDesc(),
                            const Spacing(),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 16,
                            ),
                            ElevatedButton(
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  onSurface: Colors.white),
                              onPressed: null,
                              child: Text('Add to Cart',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16)),
                            ),
                            const Spacing(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Spacing extends StatelessWidget {
  const Spacing({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const SizedBox(
      height: 16,
    );
  }
}

class RectButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  const RectButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.label,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 32,
      width: 32,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white)),
      child: Center(
          child: Text(
        label,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
      )),
    );
  }
}

class ProductNameAndPrice extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductNameAndPrice({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text(
          'Product 1',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 250, 235, 235), fontSize: 30),
        ),
        Text(
          '\u{20B9}${150}',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ProductDesc extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductDesc({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text(
            'This is a good product with \nexcellent quality. purchase it as soon as possible! \nFew numbers only Left in stocks',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16, height: 1.6)),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _TabsPartState extends State<TabsPart> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.android),
                text: "Tab 1",
              ),
              Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.phone_iphone), text: "Tab 2"),
            ],
          ),
          title: Text('TutorialKart - TabBar & TabBarView'),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            Center(child: Text("Page 1")),
            Center(child: Text("Page 2")),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Please make sure you also include relevant code in the question itself, see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168904

Comment: I am new here. When I am inserting full code, its showing error. Tried removing unwanted codes. Still it shown error while posting. So I given link like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Home());
  }
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(children: [
        const ProductNameAndPrice(),
        const ProductDesc(),
        const SizedBox(height: 16),
        ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(onSurface: Colors.black),
          onPressed: null,
          child: Text('Add to Cart',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16)),
        ),
        TabBar(
          indicatorColor: Colors.grey,
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: [
            const Tab(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.widgets,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            Tab(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.widgets,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            children: const [
              Text("POSTS"),
              Text("REELS"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}

class RectButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  const RectButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.label,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 32,
      width: 32,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9),
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white)),
      child: Center(
          child: Text(
        label,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
      )),
    );
  }
}

class ProductNameAndPrice extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductNameAndPrice({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text(
          'Product 1',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30),
        ),
        Text(
          '\u{20B9}${150}',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ProductDesc extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductDesc({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Text(
            'This is a good product with \nexcellent quality. purchase it as soon as possible! \nFew numbers only Left in stocks',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16, height: 1.6)),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

try this